# generating sql script from linq through c# code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a MVC project,I am performing various CRUD operations.I am dealing with xml data,now I want to generate sql script of the each CRUD operation performed.I have tried DataContext.GetCommand() approach also and have tried converting my linq to ToString() but I am unable to get the sql script or query.Please suggest how to achieve this.

Following is my sample code of various CRUD operations:

1) Select Operation

```
{
        var languagesList = (from ccbtlanguage in Context.tblCCBT_Language
                             join stepPageXML in Context.tblCCBT_Step_Page_Text_Xml
                                 on ccbtlanguage.Lan_Id equals stepPageXML.Lan_Id
                             where
                                 (stepPageXML.Pro_Id == productId)
                             select new StepPageData
                                 {
                                     LanguageId = ccbtlanguage.Lan_Id,
                                     LanguageName = ccbtlanguage.Lan_Language
                                 }).Distinct().ToList();
        return languagesList;
    }
```

2) Update Operation

```
   public void UpdateXMLKeyValue(int xmlId, string xmlLDataString)
    {
        if (xmlLDataString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("XMLDataString");
        var xmlDataString = Context.tblCCBT_Step_Page_Text_Xml.First(p => p.Xml_Id == xmlId);
        xmlDataString.Xml_XmlData = xmlLDataString;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Please suggest how to generate sql query or sql script from this or suggest some other way by which I can generate script of crud operation through c# code.I mean either generating script from sql query.Thanx

Comment: You could simply profile your SQL server and see the SQL query generated from the mentioned LINQ..

Comment: actually I want to generate a script which can be saved on my system and then I can run this script whenever required on other servers too.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [Linq-to-SQL Debug Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer), or just hover your mouse over your Linq-to-SQL query (tooltip should show generated SQL), or access:

```
context.GetCommand(query).CommandText
```

Comment: I tried this earlier also but getting exception-"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XMLViewer.Services.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: did you install the LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer ?

Comment: yes,but it gives exception-"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XMLViewer.Services.dll but was not handled in user code"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework you can enable Entity Framework logging.

For example in your Context's constructor you can add

```
Public SomeContextConstructor()
{
    AddDebugLogging() // Call the debug method for the log
}

// Have this method in your context class
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private void AddDebugLogging()
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => Debug.Write(string.Format("EF Log: {0}", s));
    }
```

So once you have done ran your code in Visual studio this will appear in the console. You can go ahead and run this sql script. It's good if you want to see what Entity Framework is doing in the background. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would also profile the SQL Server to get the queries. As LINQ generated queries are often not generated in a manner that is easily human readable I would then clean them up to make them more maintainable and turn them into stored procedures (Especially if you want to be able to use them on other servers.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, unless the data on all your servers are exactly the same, to try to capture the sql output from linq statements and reissue the sql commands on another server is dangerous as the sql output depends on the actual data on the first server. For example, if you have two servers that have records with the same Xml_Id, but have different values for their identity column, then this can end up updating the wrong record.

You would be better to try to determine the sql directly.

Secondly, your update routine has a `.First(..)` command but does not issue a order by, so I suspect that you are expecting only record for each Xml_Id (ie `.First(..)` should actually be `.Single(...)`. If so, then your sql maybe as simple as

```
DECLARE @xmlID Int = ...
DECLARE @xmlString VarChar(1000) = '...'

UPDATE [tblCCBT_Step_Page_Text_Xml]
SET [Xml_XmlData] =  @xmlString
WHERE [Xml_Id] = @Xml_Id
```

Comment: thanx for reply but this is only for update and that too you have mentioned it manually but I want automatically generated sql query which EF is using to perform operations,is there any way to do that?